# In react, how to pass a dynamic link in sms href?

Tags: reactjs

React-share is a nifty tool but.... doesn't have sharable sms support that I can find. Need some pointers. //will send virtual coffee as a thanks!B)

The challenge: share a dynamically created product url as a text message, with the dynamic description and url.

I have tried several link additions, but not able to accomplish the result I am looking for. Here is most recent try:

`` <a href={`sms://01134?&amp;body${description}%20${url}`} className="social-link"><FontAwesome name="share" /></a> ``

Another one I tried (which is what I use for non-dynamic links) at least drops text into the body is:
`<a href="sms://01134?&amp;body=Hi%20You've%20got%20to%20see%20this." className="social-link"><FontAwesome name="share" /></a>`

Comment: Have you tried without the `&amp;` in the href?

Comment: @AntoineGagnon It added the url as the phone number, but nothing on body - closer.

Answer (score 0):

After working this through, here is what we ended up going with, no phone number at all, just the description and url in the body of the message.

First:

```
const objectEncode = object => {
    const str = [];
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
        str.push(`${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(object[key])}`);
    });
    return str.join('&');
};

export default objectEncode;
```

Then:

```
import objectEncode from '../../../utils/objectEncode';
```

Then within the component:

```
render(){
const smsBody = objectEncode({ body: `${description} ${url}` });

return (
<a href={`sms://?&${smsBody}`} className="social-link">
    <FontAwesome name="commenting" />
</a>
);
}
```